# Toggle Button will not close - MVC 5/Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a login button with a dropdown arrow. Upon clicking the arrow it expands to show my login field. However, I cannot ever close that menu once it opens.

Is there a way to either click on the page and make it close up, or to re-click the login button to close it, or both ways(preferred)?

The view on initial load

[image]

The view after clicking Login (get's stuck open and will not close)

[image]

My code

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">      
  <li>
    <div class="btn-group navbar-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" style="margin-top:7px">Login</button>
      <button data-toggle="dropdown" style="margin-top:7px" class="btn btn-default dropdown-backdrop"><span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color: darkcyan; width: 200px; text-align:center">
        <li><input type="text" style="margin-top: 10px; width:80%; text-align:center; " name="username" placeholder="Username" /></li>
        <li><input type="password" style="margin-top: 10px; width: 80%; text-align: center" name="password" placeholder="Password" /> </li>
        <li><button type="submit" style="width:80%; margin-top:6px" class="btn btn-group-lg btn-success" id="loginLink" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Login",  "Account")';return false;">Login</button></li>
        <li><button type="submit" style="width: 80%; margin-top: 6px" class="btn btn-group-lg btn-warning" id="registerLink" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Register",  "Account")';return false;">Register</button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Side Question: Is there a simple way to have this box open on the side of the login button? I would like the top's of the button and menu (on open) aligned, and set to the right of the button rather than below it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `.dropdown-backdrop` class from your button :

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">      
  <li>
    <div class="btn-group navbar-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" style="margin-top:7px">Login</button>
      <button data-toggle="dropdown" style="margin-top:7px" class="btn btn-default"><span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color: darkcyan; width: 200px; text-align:center">
        <li><input type="text" style="margin-top: 10px; width:80%; text-align:center; " name="username" placeholder="Username" /></li>
        <li><input type="password" style="margin-top: 10px; width: 80%; text-align: center" name="password" placeholder="Password" /> </li>
        <li><button type="submit" style="width:80%; margin-top:6px" class="btn btn-group-lg btn-success" id="loginLink" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Login",  "Account")';return false;">Login</button></li>
        <li><button type="submit" style="width: 80%; margin-top: 6px" class="btn btn-group-lg btn-warning" id="registerLink" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Register",  "Account")';return false;">Register</button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

To get it opening on the right side of your button, add this CSS :

```
.navbar-right .dropdown-menu {
    top:4px;
    right: -204px;
}
```

To avoid your dropdown to be closed when you click inside your form, add this JS :

```
$('.dropdown-menu').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[<kbd>**Bootply**</kbd>](http://www.bootply.com/I7EZeivaHI)

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you very much! Quick question, is the right:-204 simply the length of the Login button? or the distance from the right-side of the page? I am still new with CSS. Thank you!

Comment: @Austin `204px` is your dropdown width (`200px`) plus a `4px` margin.

Comment: So I found a random issue. The reason I had to use '.dropdown-backdrop' was because now when I click in the textbox of username/password the menu closes. Anyway to keep that open while I am interacting with those inputs?

Comment: @Austin You should add a few JS lines to get it working, see my edit.